# Android ViewPager FragmentManager cannot be applied error

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using pager view in the regular way. in the code below I get the error: `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be applied to android.app.FragmentManager`. I checked all the solutions for this and implemented them as it can be seen (the import's seems OK), and still I have this error...

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;  //The number of pages to show.
    private static ViewPager mPager;  //The pager widget
    private static PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;  //The pager adapter

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        //Next line is error
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MyFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. Accordingly to the imports of your class you are using the `Fragment` from the support's library

Comment: Thanks that's the answer